# Django pagination error with views & template

Tags: django, templates, view, paginator

I have a database, Entries, and I want to have the items in the current `Entry` displayed in the template `entry.html`. Then I want in the sidebar to have a link to the previous entry (if it exists) and the next entry (if it exists). This is my current views.py:

```
def entry(request, projects_id=1, entries_id=1):
    entries_list = Entries.objects.filter(project_id=projects_id)
    paginator = Paginator(entries_list, 1)

    page = request.GET.get('page')
    try:
        all_entries = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        all_entries = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        all_entries = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
    return render_to_response('entry.html',
                                {'projects': Projects.objects.get(id=projects_id),
                                'entry': Entries.objects.get(project_id=projects_id, entry_unique=entries_id), 
                                'all_entries': all_entries}
                                )
```

This is my current paginator call code in the template:

```
{% if all_entries.has_previous %}
<a href="/projects/get/{{projects.id}}/entries/get/{{entry.entry_unique|add:"-1"}}"><img src="/static/assets/img/arrow_left.png" width="40"></a>
{% endif %}
{% if all_entries.has_next %}
<a href="/projects/get/{{projects.id}}/entries/get/{{entry.entry_unique|add:"1"}}"><img src="/static/assets/img/arrow_right.png" width="40"></a>
{% endif %}
```

The problem right now is that it only shows me the right arrow, never the left, and it doesn't base it on whether or not there's more Entries after the current one. I have it set up so that entry_unique and the id field are different for each entry, as I want the entries to increment by 1 per project, instead of site-wide, just in case that has anything to do with it.

This is my model for Entries:

```
class Entries(models.Model):
    project_id = models.ForeignKey(Projects)
    entry_unique = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    entry_pubdate = models.DateTimeField('date published')
```

So my major issue is that, while my Entries table has an `id` column, `project_id` is how I determine what Project owns the Entry, and `entry_unique` increments by one per entry per project so that Entry 1 is 1, Entry 2 is 2, regardless of what the `id` column is.

However, when using paginator, it doesn't ever show me a previous_entry arrow, only a next_entry arrow, and that doesn't have anything to do with whether or not there's another entry_unique. So in essence I'm sorting by project_id to determine which entries I'm working with, but I need to manipulate those entries by entry_unique.

EDIT: Last but not least, it looks like has_next only returns true if there's another project_id that's higher up, so if I go to my highest-numbered project, then has_next returns false and it won't show me a right arrow. But I still can't get has_previous to work at all.

Comment: Why you simply don't use `Pagination`?

Comment: I didn't know about Pagination. Would I essentially import paginator into my views, set it to display 1 object at a time, and then if paginator.has_previous() is false then don't show the left arrow, and if paginator.has_next() is false then don't show the right arrow?

Comment: Thank you, I updated the question with the new set of errors I'm having from switching to pagination. The paginator seems to be working but it isn't pulling the correct set of data.

Comment: {%for n in all_entries.paginator.page_range%}
    <li><a href="theurl">{{n}}</a></li>
{%endfor%}

The code above show you all the pages paste it into the code to test it! :D

Comment: That part works to show me all entries, but how do I get it to work from my unique entry number? Entries are owned by projects, so there is an id for the entire table, but "entry_unique" increments for each entry per project. I just want it to return true if there's a previous entry but it won't return true for *any* previous entries, and returns true for *any* next entry regardless of it existing or not. Is my Entries.objects.filter(project_id=projects_id) throwing it off? Thanks so much for the help it's been really eye-opening

Comment: Can you paste the model please? Maybe can be what you said or maybe try `{{all_entries.previous_page_number}}` instead of `{{entry.entry_unique|add:"-1"}}` and `{{all_entries.next_page_number}}` instead of `{{entry.entry_unique|add:"1"}}`

Comment: `class Entries(models.Model):
    project_id = models.ForeignKey(Projects)
    entry_unique = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    entry_pubdate = models.DateTimeField('date published')` is the model, I have an id (sitewide for *all* entries), a `project_id` for project ownership of each entry, and an `entry_unique` so each entry increments by 1 per project. Paginator needs filter not just by project_id but then increment by entry_unique

Comment: Please paste the model in the question and another person also can see the model and the explanation too.

Comment: I updated the question to include the models.py and focus the question some more. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Did you try `{{all_entries.previous_page_number}}` and  `{{all_entries.next_page_number}}`

Comment: The problem is that you're trying to use pagination completely wrong. Pagination is supposed to work over lists of objects. and you're not telling it which "page" to use, nor how many objects to a page (1).

Answer (score 1):

OK I managed to get it to work by changing my Views.py:

```
def entry(request, projects_id=1, entries_id=1):
    current_entry = Entries.objects.get(project_id=projects_id, entry_unique=entries_id)
    current_entry_unique = current_entry.entry_unique
    entry_previous = current_entry_unique
    entry_previous -= 1
    if Entries.objects.filter(project_id=projects_id, entry_unique=entry_previous).exists():
        prev_entry = Entries.objects.get(project_id=projects_id, entry_unique=entry_previous)
    else:
        prev_entry = None
    entry_next = current_entry.entry_unique
    entry_next += 1
    if Entries.objects.filter(project_id=projects_id, entry_unique=entry_next).exists():
        next_entry = Entries.objects.get(project_id=projects_id, entry_unique=entry_next)
    else:
        next_entry = None
    return render_to_response('entry.html',
                                {'projects': Projects.objects.get(id=projects_id),
                                'entry': Entries.objects.get(project_id=projects_id, entry_unique=entries_id),
                                'prev_entry': prev_entry,
                                'next_entry': next_entry }
                                )
```

And then my entry.html looks like this:

```
{% if prev_entry %}
<a href="/projects/get/{{projects.id}}/entries/get/{{entry.entry_unique|add:"-1"}}"><img src="/static/assets/img/arrow_left.png" width="40"></a>
{% endif %}
{% if next_entry %}
<a href="/projects/get/{{projects.id}}/entries/get/{{entry.entry_unique|add:"1"}}"><img src="/static/assets/img/arrow_right.png" width="40"></a>
{% endif %}
```

It may not be pretty but it is doing what I want it to do. There may be ways to get it to work more nicely, though.

Answer (score 0):

Without Paginator:

```
def entry(request, projects_id, entries_id):

    entries_in_project = Entries.objects.filter(project_id=projects_id)
    entry = get_object_or_404(entries_in_project, entry_unique=entries_id)
    try:
        prev_entry_id = entries_in_project.filter(entry_unique__lt=entries_id)
            .order_by('-entry_unique').values('entry_unique')[:1][0]['entry_unique']
    except IndexError:
        prev_entry_id = None
    try:
        next_entry_id = entries_in_project.filter(entry_unique__gt=entries_id)
            .order_by('entry_unique').values('entry_unique')[:1][0]['entry_unique']
    except IndexError:
        next_entry_id = None

    return render_to_response('entry.html',{
        'projects': Projects.objects.get(id=projects_id), 'entry': entry,
        'next_entry_id': next_entry_id, 'prev_entry_id': prev_entry_id,
    })
```

A Better Way:

All of this could be replaced with built-in functionality:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#order-with-respect-to

```
class Entries(models.Model):
    project_id = models.ForeignKey(Projects)
    entry_pubdate = models.DateTimeField('date published')

    class Meta:
        order_with_respect_to = 'project_id'

def entry(request, projects_id, entries_id):

    entry = get_object_or_404(Entries,project_id=projects_id, id=entries_id)

    next_entry = entry.get_next_in_order()
    prev_entry = entry.get_previous_in_order()

    return render_to_response('entry.html',{
        'projects': Projects.objects.get(id=projects_id), 'entry': entry,
        'next_entry': next_entry, 'prev_entry': prev_entry,
    })
```

In entry.html:

```
{% if next_entry %}<a href="{{ next_entry.get_absolute_url }}">Next</a>{% endif %}
{% if prev_entry %}<a href="{{ prev_entry.get_absolute_url }}">Previous</a>{% endif %}
```

Comment: The 'Without Paginator' code gives me this error: `'dict' object has no attribute 'entry_unique'` for the next_entry_id if I'm on entry 1 and the same error but for prev_entry_id if I'm on entry 2 or later. I tried the built-in functionality way but it gives me a `.order` error in the 'fields list' if I try it that way and I don't think it will work because it's very important each set of entries in a project starts with a user-visible id of 1 and go up from there, which was why I had the 'entry_unique' column